# Two minimum values in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
selection = {[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]}';
AIC = [0.00 0.01 0.00]';
for ii = 1:size(selection,1);
  sizer(ii) = size(selection{ii,1},2);
end
sizer = sizer';

pick = selection{AIC == min(AIC)}
```

See the above example,

I am trying to select the minimum AIC which as the highest sizer value,

I would like 'pick' to select [1,2,3] instead of [1].

Thanks

Comment: You mean `pick=selection{max(sizer)}`? Why do you need `AIC` for this particular thing?

Comment: I want to only use sizer if the AIC is the minimum, as the AIC has two 0 values I then need to move onto sizer to choose the one i actually want

Comment: Ah that makes more sense.

Comment: If you want to thank the answered, accept their answer and upvote it, do not break the question

Comment: yes apologies done and done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` with `@size` to get all the sizes, and use `max` to get max size:

```
sizes = cellfun(@size, selection, 'UniformOutput', false);
pick = max([sizes{AIC == min(AIC)}])
```

Comment: do I not even need sizer?

Comment: @user30609 nope, you don't. Use vector indexing instead of loop when possible

Comment: @user30609 I edited my answer according to the information you provided.
StackOverFlow is not a code service, no one has to give you an answer, and especially not immediately so be patient.

Comment: sorry I wasn't being impatient